# Background color using ncurses on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ncurses

first post here so I apologize for any errors.

Basically, when I run my code, everything works properly except for changing the background color. For some reason it is always grey. I'm attempting to change it to black but it's not working and I'm not sure why.

The main part of my code that I believe should be changing the background color is this: 
wattron(mainWindow, COLOR_BLACK);

Any help to figure out how to change my background to Black would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys!

Here is what I have so far in case it helps give some context for my problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <time.h>

// Variables
int nlines;
int ncols;
int x;
int y;
int y0;
int x0;
int input;

// Constants
const int MAX_LINES = 10;
const int MAX_COLUMNS = 10;

// Main function
int main(void) {
    WINDOW * mainWindow;

    // Initialize ncurses
    if ( (mainWindow = initscr()) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize ncurses!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Call function to use color
    start_color();

    // Create my own color pairs
    init_pair(1, COLOR_CYAN, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(2, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_RED);

    // First clear off the screen
    clear();

    // Move the cursor
    y = 8;
    x = 30;
    move(y, x);

    // Refresh
    refresh();

    // Test output - working
    // printw("Testing...");

    waddch(mainWindow, 'T' | A_UNDERLINE | COLOR_PAIR(1));
    waddch(mainWindow, 'E' | A_UNDERLINE | COLOR_PAIR(2));
    waddch(mainWindow, 'S' | A_UNDERLINE | COLOR_PAIR(1));
    waddch(mainWindow, 'T' | A_UNDERLINE | COLOR_PAIR(2));
    waddch(mainWindow, 'I' | A_UNDERLINE | COLOR_PAIR(1));
    waddch(mainWindow, 'N' | A_UNDERLINE | COLOR_PAIR(2));
    waddch(mainWindow, 'G' | A_UNDERLINE | COLOR_PAIR(1));
    waddch(mainWindow, '.' | A_UNDERLINE | COLOR_PAIR(2));
    waddch(mainWindow, '.' | A_UNDERLINE | COLOR_PAIR(1));
    waddch(mainWindow, '.' | A_UNDERLINE | COLOR_PAIR(1));
    waddch(mainWindow, '.' | A_UNDERLINE | COLOR_PAIR(2));

    // Make background a different color
    wattron(mainWindow, COLOR_BLACK);

    // Hold until user inputs a character
    input =  getch();

    // Clean up
    delwin(mainWindow);
    endwin();
    refresh();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`wbkgd(WINDOW *win, chtype ch)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wbkgd)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried using wbkgd(WINDOW *win, chtype ch) or in my case wbkgd(mainWindow, COLOR_BLACK) and even made sure to do a refresh() after but it wasn't working. The background is still grey. I attempted to call use_default_colors() then do everything and it changed the background from grey to the normal purple color but never actually changed it to black. I apologize but I'm still a bit confused :/

Comment: Turns out grey is black for me...strange but any other color worked perfectly just like you said. My black must be a bit off so I'll just tweak that and it should be good. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the call `wattron(WINDOW* win, chtype ch)` you cannot use COLOR_BLACK as `ch` because COLOR_BLACK is an integer, not an attribute (value of `chtype`). You should call this function using `COLOR_PAIR`:

```
wattron(mainWindow, COLOR_PAIR(0)); // The pair number 0 is the terminal's default pair (white foreground, black background).
```

Note that `wattron` only enables specified attributes. If you want to set a background (it's reset attributes of each cell) of a window, you will better use `wbkgd(WINDOW *win, chtype ch)`. Documentation of it you can find in the [wbkgd(3ncurses) manual page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/ncurses-doc/wbkgd.3ncurses.en.html).

The ncurses' tutorial that helped me the most is [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/). I recommend you reading the 10th Colors section.